# Trying to eliminate the types module in python code

Tags: python

Is saying:

```
if not callable(output.write):
   raise ValueError("Output class must have a write() method")
```

The same as saying:

```
if type(output.write) != types.MethodType:
   raise exceptions.ValueError("Output class must have a write() method")
```

I would rather not use the types module if I can avoid it.

Comment: Yes I do realize I misspelled module and yes I do want to know if the exceptions.ValueError is necessary.

Comment: What does "necessary" mean in that context?

Comment: There's an edit button. If you realize you misspelled something, you can go back and fix it.

Comment: Thanks and by "necessary" I mean is saying exceptions.ValueError the same thing as saying ValueError.

Comment: Yes they're the same thing and you shouldn't ask two different questions at the same time.

Comment: Why do you _want_ to avoid the `types` module? It’s there, in the stdlib, and all it does is expose a bunch of types that are already builtin but don’t have convenient names otherwise, so what’s the harm in importing it?

Comment: @abarnert Well, its funny because it is the use of the types module that prevents this old legacy py2 code from playing with the new py3 scripts. Basically, I am attempting to change a myriad of scripts enough so that they will play well with the py3 scripts. A few of the methods in types that use to exist are now gone; hence, I need to find an alternate method of accomplishing the same logic.

Comment: @Vysero Eliminating use of those methods obviously makes sense. But, even if that can't be automatically detected (and I'm pretty sure it should be doable—e.g., `2to3` or `modernize` knows about them), using the results of `grep -r 'types\.`as a list of things to look at and test, rather than as a list of things that have to be rewritten even if they make sense and work in 3.x, seems like a better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they are not the same.

[`callable(output.write)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable) just checks whether `output.write` is callable. Things that are callable include:

- Bound method objects (whose type is `types.MethodType`).
- Plain-old functions (whose type is `types.FunctionType`)
- `partial` instances wrapping bound method objects (whose type is `functools.partial`)
- Instances of you own custom callable class with a `__call__` method that are designed to be indistinguishable from bound method objects (whose type is your class).
- Instances of a subclass of the bound method type (whose type is that subclass).
- …

`type(output.write) == types.MethodType` accepts only the first of these. Nothing else, not even subclasses of `MethodType`, will pass. (If you want to allow subclasses, use `isinstance(output.write, types.MethodType)`.)

The former is almost certainly what you want. If I've monkeypatched an object to replace the `write` method with something that acts just like a `write` method when called, but isn't implemented as a bound method, why would your code want to reject my object?

---

As for your side question in the comments:

> I do want to know if the exceptions.ValueError is necessary

No, it's not.

In Python 2.7, the builtin exceptions are also available in the `exceptions` module:

```
>>> ValueError is exceptions.ValueError
True
```

In Python 3, they were moved to `builtins` along with all the other builtins:

```
>>> ValueError is builtins.ValueError
True
```

But either way, the only reason you'd ever need to refer to its module is if you hid `ValueError` with a global of the same name in your own module.

---

One last thing:

As user2357112 points out in a comment, your solution doesn't really ensures anything useful.

The most common problem is almost certainly going to be `output.write` not existing at all. In which case you're going to get an `AttributeError` rather than the `ValueError` you wanted. (If this is acceptable, you don't need to check *anything*—just call the method and you'll get an `AttributeError` if it doesn't exist, and a `TypeError` if it does but isn't callable.) You could solve that by using `getattr(output, 'write', None)` instead of `output.write`, because `None` is not callable.

The next most common problem is probably going to be `output.write` existing, and being callable, but with the wrong signature. Which means you'll still get the same `TypeError` you were trying to avoid when you try to call it. You could solve that by, e.g., using the `inspect` module.

But if you really want to do all of this, you should probably be factoring it all out into an [ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html). ABCs only have built-in support for checking that abstract methods exist as attributes; it doesn't check whether they're callable, or callable with the right signature. But it's not that hard to extend that support. (Or, maybe better, just grabbing one of the interface/protocol modules off PyPI.) And I think something like `isinstance(output, StringWriteable)` would declare your intention a lot better than a bunch of lines involving `getattr` or `hasattr`, type checking, and `inspect` grubbing.

Comment: Thanks, any ideas about how I might make the comparison without using types.MethodType()?

Comment: @Vysero My advice is to not do the comparison unless absolutely necessary. In fact, without seeing your code, I’d guess you don’t need to do anything at all here, and could just duck type and handle the error, but if you do need a test, `callable` is far more likely to be what you need than the exact type check.

Comment: @Vysero If you _do_ need an exact type check for some reason, you can always access the same type by calling `type` on something you know is a method. For example, define a `class Dummy` with a `def method`, then `type(Dummy().method)`. But it’s much simpler, and clearer, to use `types.MethodType`, so I can’t imagine why you’d want to avoid it.

Comment: @Vysero Or, if you're actively _trying_ to make your code unreadable, try something like `type(type('.',(),{'m':lambda:0})().m)` or `type((lambda:0).__get__(0))`. That's untested, but either one should give you the same type as `types.MethodType` in a pretty obscure way.

Comment: Well I guess my method takes in some output and I just want to make sure the output will have certain methods like a write method and in another case where I am saying:  type(output.NewPos) != types.MethodType to check if it has a NewPos method:

Comment: @Vysero In general, the way to do that in Python is to just not do that. Without your check, an `output` that doesn't  have a `write` method will raise an exception. With your check, an `output` that doesn't have a `write` method will raise an exception. Either way, the exception will show exactly what's wrong with `output` in the traceback. So, what have you gained?

Comment: If you're going to check, you should probably also check that `output.write` actually exists, too, with `hasattr(output, 'write')`. It's much more likely that you'll receive an object with no `write` attribute than that you'll receive an object with a non-callable `write` attribute.

Comment: @user2357112 Under the covers, `hasattr` just does a `getattr` under a `try`, so it might be cleaner to just stick this `output.write` check in an `except AttributeError:`. But then it's hard to be sure what looks cleanest when someone's already committed to violating EAFP and normal idioms, so…

Comment: @abarnert Well currently I have altered it to: `if "write" not in dir(output) raise ValueError("Output class must have a write() method")` Obviously, this is only checking for the word write (it may not be a write method) but at least this can be compiled by both a py2 and a py3 interpreter.

Comment: @Vysero `hasattr` or `getattr` is a better way to check that than `dir`, and will work with Python 2.7 (or even, say, 2.3) as well as 3.x, and will handle more edge cases. But the best way to handle it is to just use it and handle `AtttibuteError`, because that handles all possible cases, even classes using a dynamic `__getattribute__`. In general, the more you try to fight against Python’s dynamic typing instead of using it, the more work you have to do and the more edge cases you fail to deal with.

Comment: @Vysero But as I said elsewhere, if you’re really committed to pre-checking interfaces at this level, you’d do a lot better to just grab one of the interface/protocol libs off PyPI that wrap it all up, so all you have to do is declare what your interface looks like (including even method signatures) and then ask the mechanism to check whether the object meets that interface or not. This is an unusual thing to need, but if you really need it (even though you probably don’t), better to use code that’s already tested and has a clean API than to try to hack it all together from scratch.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but your saying I should just `if not hasattr(output, 'write'):
      raise AttributeError("Output class must have a write() method")` or are you saying I shouldn't check at all because if someone calls output.write and it doesn't have that method its simply going to raise the same error? If that is the case how do I specify the error message?

Comment: @Vysero If you want an `AttributeError` to be raised, you don't have to check anything—`output.write` will already raise that. If you want to change the text of the error, or if you want to make sure it's a `ValueError` instead, you can just do the `output.write` inside an `except AttributeError:` that raises your exception. Or you can use `if not hasattr(output, 'write')` and raise one, but that's a less complete test.

Comment: @abarnert Oh, do you mean catch the ValueError whenever I use output.write? The only problem with that is that I call output.write like 10+ times. This is why I am trying to just catch the problem (if there is one) right at the beginning of the class. In order to save myself the burden of re-writing the same code 10+ times.

Comment: @Vysero Look at [this code](https://repl.it/repls/GreedySparklingCharmap). Ignore the testing machinery at the bottom, just look at the different `Call` functions. Notice that using `dir` rejects the `WriteGetattr` class incorrectly, and also accepts the `WriteMethodWrongSig` class incorrectly (leading to a `TypeError` later). Do you see why this is a problem?

Comment: @Vysero Meanwhile, you only have to catch an `AttributeError` or `TypeError` once—either around the first call, or all the calls, or, maybe best, in a wrapper function that you write that calls `output.write(buf)` inside a `try` and remaps the exception as appropriate.

Comment: @abarnert Okay, I think I understand. So I guess what I should be saying is: `if not output:
      pass

    if not hasattr(output, 'write') or not callable(output.write):
      raise ValueError('Output class must have a write() method')` , would be more robust and correct?

Comment: @Vysero More robust and correct that checking `dir` and `type(output.write)`, but still not as robust, correct, or simple as just using `except`.

Comment: @ abarnert Well I want to use the most robust, correct and simple method. I am not sure what you mean by using `except`. Would I need to set up exception handling blocks?

Comment: @Vysero I don't know why you want this particular error instead of the normal meaningful exceptions you get without doing anything, but if you really want them, and want to avoid a bunch of tests to convert the exception, as I said before, you can just write a wrapper. [Here's an example](https://repl.it/repls/OutrageousMurkyFibonacci).

Comment: @abarnert Thanks you have been a great help I appreciate it!